# Layout with Fixed and Fluid columns and clear floats

Tags: html, css

I need to create a two column layout with:

1. Left column fixed and right column fluid;
2. Each column has a window with a Head (with tabs and menu) and a Body.

The Fixed / Fluid layout is working but on the right column there is a **space between the head div (tabs) and the body div (body of window 2)**:

[image: Preview]

I created a Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4sk3bkde/

The problem seems to happen when I use the **.clear** class to clear floats:

```
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**The HTML code is:**

```
<div class="wrapper clear">

  <div class="fixed">

    <div class="window">
      <div class="head clear">
        <ul class="tabs clear">
          <li>Tab 1</li>
          <li>Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Body of window 1
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="fluid">

    <div class="window">
      <div class="head clear">
        <ul class="tabs clear">
          <li>Tab 1</li>
          <li>Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Body of window 2
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**And the CSS code is:**

```
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.fluid,
.fixed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixed {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}

.fluid {
  margin-left: 250px;
}

div.window {
}

div.head {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ul.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul.tabs li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

**Why do I get this problem when using clear? How to solve this?**

Comment: you must use clear after you done with float, clear only will fill your float elements.

Comment: You have a bunch of floating elements. The clearfixes are going to try and clear as many floats as they can at every opportunity you give.

Comment: Yes, I added a clear on every element which contains child elements with floats ... The question is why do I get that space

Answer (score 0):

You do not want your display to be table unless you are trying to mimic table like behavior.

The relevant change I would make would be change the `display` to 
either `inline-block` or `inline-table`

```
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
```

As you can see in the snippet, change in the body content does not affect the fluid header size if the `display` were `table`.

```css
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-table;
  clear: both;
}

.fluid,
.fixed {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fixed {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
}

.fluid {
  margin-left: 250px;
}

div.window {
}

div.head {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ul.tabs {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

ul.tabs li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.2/mootools-core-compat.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper clear">

  <div class="fixed">

    <div class="window">
      <div class="head clear">
        <ul class="tabs clear">
          <li>Tab 1</li>
          <li>Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Body of window 1<br>
        Body of window 1<br>
        Body of window 1<br>
        Body of window 1<br>
        Body of window 1<br>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="fluid">

    <div class="window">
      <div class="head clear">
        <ul class="tabs clear">
          <li>Tab 1</li>
          <li>Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Body of window 2<br>
        Body of window 2<br>
        Body of window 2<br>
        Body of window 2<br>
        Body of window 2<br>
        
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think maybe a better solution would be to use a specific clear for head: .clear { overflow: hidden; } ... This works ... I am not use if using inline-block will create other problems ... Will it? Which clearfix do you use?

Comment: Check this link http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

Give fluid class float right and set the width.
https://goo.gl/I6nLss
Bcoz fluid style is not in float but fixed is in float